# Queuing models in R, $\lambda$ Little

Tags: modeling, probability-distributions, simulation, queuing-theory, r

It's noted that the number of folks in a stationary system will maintain an average equal to the rate of arrival multiplied by the mean of the service distribution.

The formula $L = \lambda w$ is valid for any queueing model in steady-state, where $L$ and $w$ are long-term steady-state average values respectively, and $\lambda$ denotes the arrival rate to the system.

We can add up the total service time in the system as follows:

$$\sum w_{j} = \sum i T_i$$

where $T_i$ represents the time units in which $i$ entities were in the system.

But things are always more interesting with sample sizing and simulating results, so say in $5000$ iterations we estimate a state of a system in 1-min intervals, between the first minute and the last arrival at a determined time.

So suppose we use a random interarrival rate of $\lambda = 2$ per minute and the service distribution is $N(8,1)$ minutes for the system.

How can I simulate this model in R, using `rexp()` and `rnorm()`? I also want to display in `ts()` to show in time plot.

Comment: While I think the topic does fit into our site, asking for a model in R will probably get more attention on SO (see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BR%5D+lambda for some questions there). But let's see what our other users will come up to answer your question.

Comment: I came up with a portion, perhaps there can be come feedback see below

Comment: Is your question about OR concepts in the queuing model, e.g., some aspect of Little’s Law, or is it about the implementation of some functions in R? If the latter, I agree with @JakobS that the question might get more response on SO. If the former, I think the question could use some clarification about what exactly you are asking.

Comment: It was more oh do we set this up programmatically, but also a question could be why would a distribution of outcomes (ala simulation) provide and more rigor than any other methods

Comment: I am happy to expand my answer if you can refine your question appropriately. We are all seeking to keep the answered rate high.

Answer (score 7):

Not directly answering your question of how to code it manually but for discrete simulation of queues in R I would strongly recommend the `simmer` package. The minimal code for your example would look like this (adapted from the tutorial).

```
library(simmer)
library(simmer.plot)
lambda <- 2

queue <- trajectory() %>%
  seize("server", amount=1) %>%
  timeout(function() {rnorm(1, 8, 1)}) %>%
  release("server", amount=1)

env <- simmer() %>%
  add_resource("server", capacity=1) %>%
  add_generator("arrival", queue, function() {rnorm(1, lambda)}) %>%
  run(until=100000)


resources <- get_mon_resources(env)
arrivals <- get_mon_arrivals(env)

plot(resources, metric = "usage", items = "server")
plot(arrivals, metric = "flow_time")
```

However, looking at the plot of flow times I am unsure if you conceived a stable queuing system - for mean = 1 in the service time it looks better:

Service Time Mean 8:
[image: mean = 8]

Service Time Mean 1:
[image: mean = 1]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I’ll share what I came up with!

Comment: Have fun - it is a powerful yet neat package. I updated my answer to be a bit more illustrative.

Answer (score 1):

So far this is what I have come up with

```r
lambda <- 2
interarrivals <- rexp(5000,lambda)  ## (2 items per minute)
```

Provided the $\mu$ we expect that the interarrivals is about half a minute

```r
mean(interarrivals) <- 0.516
service.times <- rnorm(5000, mean=8,sd=1)
```

where the service distribution is $N(8,1)$

```r
arrival.times <- cumsum(interarrivals)
departure.times <- arrival.times+service.times
```

Where I am having issues is determining how many individuals remain in the system at time 1-min to the last.

I am having issues conceptualizing the model - this is what you are supposed to estimate (Little's law), which states that rate of arrival = 2 units per minute × mean of the service distribution = 8.

Comment: my intent is to convert the system state to a time.series `ts()` so I can plot.